# How to select an nth level element in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to select an nth level element in CSS

Below is an example code

```css
div>div>p {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<h1>Heading</h1>

<div>
  <h2>Random sibling</h2>
  <p>First Level child.</p>
  <div>
    <h2>Random sibling</h2>
    <p>Second Level child.</p>
    <div>
      <h2>Random sibling</h2>
      <p>Third Level child.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <span><p>Descendent child.</p></span>
</div>

<p>Not a child.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I only want to select the second level child and prevent third level child from being styled

How do we accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to add an identifier to the first `<div>` element and then walk through the children tree by parent > child children selector as follows:

```css
.main > div:first-of-type > p {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<h1>Heading</h1>

<div class='main'>
  <h2>Random sibling</h2>
  <p>First Level child.</p>
  <div>
    <h2>Random sibling</h2>
    <p>Second Level child.</p>
    <div>
      <h2>Random sibling</h2>
      <p>Third Level child.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <span><p>Descendent child.</p></span>
</div>

<p>Not a child.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why don't you use any class or id but try this on your Css code

```
div>div>p:not(:last-child) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```css
div>div>p:not(:last-child) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>

<div>
  <h2>Random sibling</h2>
  <p>First Level child.</p>
  <div>
    <h2>Random sibling</h2>
    <p>Second Level child.</p>
    <div>
      <h2>Random sibling</h2>
      <p>Third Level child.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <span><p>Descendent child.</p></span>
</div>

<p>Not a child.</p>
```